# A/C button not switching on compressor

Tags: chevrolet, ac, car

My 2007 Chevrolet Lumina has been having A/C problems lately. A couple days ago the car wasn't starting so we jumped it, later finding out that the Negative Side terminal was corroded not giving enough power to the Starter.

Yesterday, when I tried switching on the car it just died as if someone unplugged the battery. The mechanic who cleaned the terminal forgot to fully tighten it so it was unplugged when I looked at the battery. I didn't have any tools with me at hand so I had someone hold down the terminal into the battery so I was able to start the car. I immediately rushed to the mechanic so he can tighten the clamp, reaching there finding out the terminal was out of its place while I was driving. Once the mechanic tightened it I went home.

Today when I tried switching clicking the A/C button it didn't do anything. The screen wasn't showing that the A/C button was clicked, the compressor was off when I manually checked it, and no cold air was coming out. Everything else works ie. Blower/Heat/Controls for the temperature. Its just the A/C button not toggling making the compressor not switch on. I thought maybe a fuse blew but I am not really sure what fuse I am supposed to be looking at. There are 3 fuse boxes in the car, one to the left of the brake, one in the trunk, and the main one in the engine compartment.

Can anyone tell me what fuse I am supposed to be looking for? Or if you have any other advice please help me.

Pictures of fuses in Manual:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dPpB_1Es7nPomijZ4XDX7fUzV0Y3gfja/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tI3R0bvlg6SygtbYYtH2THpzS1YBCfB0jg/view
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u637qbG2Js8hGrKozgA98wVBs6_W8itE/view
Thanks,
Ebrahim

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the A/C was working just peachie before the incident with the negative battery connection, you'd want to look at fuse F2 in the underhood fuse panel. It is a 10A fuse according to your owner's manual, which would make it red in color (to help you spot it). The cover for the under hood fuse panel should have a diagram on the underside showing you exactly where the fuse is located. If the fuse shows good, you'd have to figure something else is going on with it, which could be one of the pressure switches is bad, or there may not be enough pressure in the system to allow the system to turn the compressor on. Since you're not even getting a light on the dash, I'd bet the fuse is a very good first place to look, though.

Comment: Alas. I took the F2 Fuse and the wires in-between seemed intact. I also went the extra length to buy another 10A fuse to replace it but the problem still exits. Could it be the HVAC IGN fuse?